# How do I grant access to members of a group in openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I would like to restrict LDAP bind users so that have access to only what is absolutely necessary.

For example, I have an LDAP user that is used to bind for a specific application.
*cn=app1,ou=bind-accounts,dc=example,dc=net"*

The LDAP bind user should only be able to read specific attributes for the users that need to access the application, even if they are in different OUs.

The following user specific access rules achieve my desired outcome.

```
access to dn.exact="cn=bob,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net" attrs=uid,objectClass,entry
  by dn="cn=app1,ou=bind-accounts,dc=example,dc=net" read

access to dn.exact="cn=alice,ou=users,ou=client1,ou=clients,dc=example,dc=net" attrs=uid,objectClass,entry
  by dn="cn=app1,ou=bind-accounts,dc=example,dc=net" read
```

I have the following group that includes both users that need access to the app

```
dn: cn=app1-access,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=net
cn: app1-access
objectClass: groupOfNames
description: Users permitted to access app1
member: cn=alice,ou=users,ou=client1,ou=clients,dc=example,dc=net
member: cn=bob,ou=users,dc=example,dc=net
```

What access rule would filter on members of the group, so I don't have to have the user specific rules?